How to Setup pure React Native in Google IDX(withouth Expo-CLI) with Emulator
How to use/setup pure React Native in Google IDX(cloud IDE) without Expo CLI, in **IDX **it default provides expo CLI with React Native Template **IDX **(Note: The React Native Template has the emulator included) or how to remove the EXPO dependencies in the default template.Transform TSX to JS as we remove the EXPO-CLI.
Setup Pure React Native in Google IDX with Emulator and remove Expo CLI, Remove TSX(Type-Script and add JS)

Can no body answer>>??

Did not try this out, but you could try this:

create a RN CLI project on your machine
Push it github
Importing the repos in IDX
Try setting up the machine

